# Standard error of the prediction of uniform distribution

Tags: statistics

There are $T$ people who will deposit money into bank at time $t$ which uniformly distributes on $[0,T]$. Each of them has $\dfrac{1}{T}$ money, so at time $T$ the bank will have total money of $1$. If the manager of the bank predicts that at time $t_0$, there is $\dfrac{t_0}{T}$ money deposited into the bank. What is the standard error of his prediction?

---

I have no idea how to calculate the standard error here. I know the variance of the sample mean is $\dfrac{\sqrt{(b-a)^2/12}}{\sqrt{n}}$, but I think it does not help with the prediction...

---

@Did. Yes there are $T$ people. I thought this might be an inhomogeneous Poisson process but when I looked it up in wiki I found it was not what I meant.

I am writing an essay on the liquidity of banking, and I want to extend the Diamond-Dybvig model to continuum. Since I have little statistics knowledge, I have no idea how to calculate or express the problem here.. btw thanks for your reply

Comment: You mean, T people? (And please add what you tried.)

Comment: Hint: (1) T times the money at the bank at time t_0 is the number of people depositing before time t_0 hence its distribution is binomial (T,t_0/T). (2) The standard deviation of the binomial (n,p) distribution is sqrt(np(1-p)).

Comment: @Did Why T times t0/T is the number of people depositing before time t0? I think the expectation of the number of people depositing before t should be t..

Comment: @Did I edited the question a bit to make it clear.

Comment: @Did In fact I completed the model where there are two types of people, E and L, where E prefers withdraw at Day_1 but L prefers withdraw at Day_2. If there are 40% type E people, then the number is binomial(.4,n).

Comment: "Why T times t0/T is the number of people depositing before time t0?" Who said it was? Not I. Please read carefully. "I think the expectation of the number of people depositing before t should be t." Yes it is, and the expectation of the binomial distribution (T,t/T) is t...